# How can I download a file using a button from fetched row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was able to fetch and display the data but I am unable to download the file using dowload button.

I am storing images inside a folder call images in root. [http://localhost/images/]
How can I actually download a file using this download button?

**My Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
      <title>Records</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Varela+Round|Open+Sans">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <style type="text/css">
         .bs-example{
         margin: 20px;
         }
      </style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
         $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="bs-example">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="page-header clearfix">
                     <h2 class="pull-left">Records</h2>
                  </div>
                  <?php
                     include_once 'dbconfig.php';
                     $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM book");
                     ?>
                  <?php
                     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                     ?>
                  <button type="Home" name="change" onclick="window.location.href='mgrmenu.php'">Home</button>
                  <table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Name</td>
                        <td>Age</td>
                        <td>Mobile</td>
                        <td>File</td>
                     </tr>
                     <?php
                        $i=0;
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        ?>
                     <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row["Fname"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["age"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["patientNo"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["images"];?><Button> Download</Button></td>
                     </tr>
                     <?php
                        $i++;
                        }
                        ?>
                  </table>
                  <?php
                     }
                     else{
                     echo "No result found";
                     }
                     ?>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

How can I create my download button to actually download that particular file?

Comment: I've removed [tag:sql-server] as from the tagging of [tag:phpmyadmin] (which I've also removed as it's an IDE and not related to the question) and the use of `mysqli` in the code, this is clearly MySQL. Please only tag the RDBMS(s) related to the question when posting. Thanks.

Comment: you want to download image??

Comment: @Larnu Thanks, I will keep it in mind.

Comment: @KUMAR yes I want to add a download button for that Image row.

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="/path/to/image" download>
    <img src="/path/to/image" />
 </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download any file on clicking a button you must try this:

```
<a class="btn" href="<?= $your_path_to_file ?>" download>Download File</a>
```